# Perl script to remove only matched duplicate lines?

Tags: regex, perl, duplicates

I know that hashes can be used to remove duplicate lines in a file and it removes all the duplicate lines in a file. I used the following lines to remove all duplicate lines in a file..

```
my %lines;
while (<DATA>) {
print if not $lines{$_}++;
}
```

But, i need to remove only duplicate lines with matched patterns...
Sample input file:

```
line1
line2
line3
line1 #duplicate line
line2 #duplicate line
line4
line5
```

Though both line1 and line2 are duplicated, i only want to remove duplication of line1.

output:

```
line1
line2
line3
line2 #this duplicated line need to be resumed
line4
line5
```

Any suggestion to combine hashes and regex to achieve my requirement???

Comment: What is it about line2 that makes it stay?  Is it only the first duplicate found in the file that you want removed?  Or perhaps, if a duplicate is removed, the next line is always kept?

Comment: Are comments (stuff after the `#`) supposed to be ignored when comparing with previous lines?

Comment: i need to put regex for line1 alone to delete its duplication, where as no need to modify other duplications...

Comment: You can use `sort file.txt | uniq -u` linux command to run via `perl` to remove duplicate line. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution allows you to set up a regex pattern `$check_dups` that defines which lines are susceptible to duplicate removal. If a line matches that pattern then it is removed if it has been seen before; all other lines are retained

Here, only duplicates of lines that match `/line1/` are removed as required by the example in your question

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $check_dups = qr/line1/;

my %seen;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    if ( /$check_dups/ ) {
        print unless $seen{$_}++;
    }
    else {
        print;
    }
}

__DATA__
line1
line2
line3
line1
line2
line4
line5
```

#### output

```
line1
line2
line3
line2
line4
line5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my %lines;
while (<DATA>) {
    next if $lines{$_}++ and /^line2/;
    print;
}
```

The part `/^line2/` is a regular expression which describes some data/text. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html for details.

The `next` line skips all lines which are duplicate **and** match whatever you like. You may easily negate this like `! /^line1/`;

Comment: it is not defined that how many other duplications are present in the file, it is not fixed in all scenarios, i can only have control on line1 which will present in all files for sure. At the same time, other duplication should not be removed...

Comment: The solution skips all duplicates, because `$lines{$_}++` will be false if the line was never seen and true after the first match. You may also extent this using `> 1` (removes only the second occurrence)  or `% 3` (modulo 3, matches 2 of 3 times).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the previous line being removed is the trigger that makes a duplicate exempt from being deleted and that you want comments ignored;

```
use v5.12;
use warnings;

my %lines;
my $previous_line_removed = 0;
while (<>) {
   my $original_line = $_ ;
   chomp ;
   s/\s*#.*?$// ;
   if ( $lines{$_}++ && ! $previous_line_removed ) {
        $previous_line_removed = 1 ;
   }
   else {
       print $original_line ;
       $previous_line_removed = 0 ;
   }
}
#
# when fed data above...
#
line1
line2
line3
line2 #duplicate line
line4
line5
```